# Customizing a Wordpress-generated breadcrumb link

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Good Day

I am using Wordpress, and I am using a breadcrumbs plugin (Breadcrumb NavXT). Now it works great, exept that I would like to customize the way it links to a **specific** link:

**Now here is the scenario:**

I have a page, and on the page are links to posts. So when you click on one of the links on the page, it takes you to the post. Now this posts belongs to a category named Drill Rigs, and Drill Rigs is a child category of Products.

Now on the post page, which has category 'products>drill rigs' (parent/child), the breadcrumb shows the following way:

```
Home>products>drill rigs>postname
```

Problem is, that of you click on the products link above, it takes you to the category page of products:

```
siteurl/category/products
```

and not the actual wordpress page that is called products (that contains the links linking to the posts mentioned above:

siteurl/absolute link to the page, which is a unique link eg. siteurl/803-2

Now as far as I know, you cannot change the path from a category (which are unique to posts) to a page, neither in wordpress nor the plugin.

The best way I can think of is to add custom jquery or php to the posts php page (or index/header pages) that looks for the container div containing the anchor tags that hosts the title 'products'...and then replacing that anchor tag with my custom unique page url...

How would I do this...?

Answer (score 1):

```
function the_breadcrumb() {

$sep = '/';

if (!is_front_page()) {

    echo '<div class="breadcrumbs">';
    echo '<a href="';
    echo get_option('home');
    echo '">';
    bloginfo('name');
    echo '</a>' . $sep;

    if (is_category() || is_single() ){
        the_category('title_li=');
    } elseif (is_archive() || is_single()){
        if ( is_day() ) {
            printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date() );
        } elseif ( is_month() ) {
            printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
        } elseif ( is_year() ) {
            printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
        } else {
            _e( 'Blog Archives', 'text_domain' );
        }
    }

    if (is_single()) {
        echo $sep;
        the_title();
    }

    if (is_page()) {
        echo the_title();
    }

    if (is_home()){
        global $post;
        $page_for_posts_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
        if ( $page_for_posts_id ) { 
            $post = get_page($page_for_posts_id);
            setup_postdata($post);
            the_title();
            rewind_posts();
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

}

try this hope this may help  you

Answer (score 1):

This code works with asynchron content for your posts: (to copy in functions.php)

```
function ariane() {
    $cat_id         = get_the_category()[0]->term_id;
    $breadcrumb     = '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';

    $if_parent = TRUE;

    while($if_parent == TRUE) :
        $cat_object     = get_category($cat_id);
        $cat            = $cat_object->term_id;
        $categoryURL    = get_category_link($cat);
        $name           = $cat_object->name;
        $cat_id         = $cat_object->parent;              

        $add_link       = '<li><a href="' . $categoryURL . '">' . $name . '</a></li>';

        $breadcrumb     = substr_replace($breadcrumb, $add_link, 0, 0);

        if($cat_id  == 0) :
            $if_parent = FALSE;
        endif;
    endwhile;

    echo '<ul>' . $breadcrumb . '</ul>';    
}
```

In your archive.php or in the loop WP_QUERY

```
<div class="ariane"><?php ariane(); ?></div>
```

in css :

```
.ariane ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}  
.ariane li:not(:last-child):after {
    content: '>';
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function to set your Breadcrumb  by coding :

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
if (!is_home()) {
    echo '<a href="';
    echo get_option('home');
    echo '">';
    echo "Home";//bloginfo('name');
    echo "</a> / ";
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        the_category('title_li=');
        if (is_single()) {
            echo " / ";
            the_title();
        }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo the_title();
    }
}
```

}

Put the  above code in function.php file

you  have to just call the function  where you want to show the  bredcrumb

```
<?php the_breadcrumb(); ?>
```

Hope this will help  you ...

Comment: thank you for the effort Vickey, but unfortunately it does not work...Only shows Home>Drill Rigs every time. It does not include the 'products' link in the breadcrumb

Comment: which  plugin you are useing to show product  if its wp-ecommerce then there is setting at backend for  to show product on product page  or category change that setting

Comment: sorry for the  ecommerce product  page   because on  if you are showing the category on product page then  it will  link to that   or kindly check is that your category link and product page have same url  ?  because it give the prefrence to page  first

Comment: The cat link and product page have 2 different links

Comment: check the slug in url if these are same that shuld be problum

Comment: slugs are also different. I actually fixed it with jquery - see my answer on this post...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#breadcrumbs .category[href="http://mysite.com/category/products"]').attr('href','http://mysite.com/803-2');
</script>
```

where:

```
http://mysite.com/803-2
```

is the url of the p[age I want to link to...